# Asymptotic normal-behaviour of the MLE, question about proof.

Tags: statistics, proof-verification

In this proof they prove that the MLE is asymptotically normal. But as you see, they divide by $S'(\theta)$. But what if this value is 0?, you can't divide by zero? Is there a special case when this happen, or can it never happen?

[image: Proof]

Comment: Sorry but your picture is too small to be viewed properly even on a 23inch screen.

Comment: Sorry, here is the link:http://s28.postimg.org/8px6ifo1p/proof.png You can zoom there.

Comment: Sorry, but your link's photo is identical as the one in this webpage.

Comment: Hm, it is actually quite large for me. For me the writing is basically as large as the wrinting on this webpage. Would you please try zooming in?, if you have a scrolling wheel on your mouse you can hold down the "Ctrl" button and use the weel to zoom. If you do not have a scrolling wheel could you please try holding the "Ctrl" button down and press the "+" button uintil it is big enough for you. You zoom out again by holding down the "Ctrl" button and pressing "-" uintil it is zoomed out enough.

Comment: I wrote the first comment after I already tried to zoom in.

Comment: There may be something wrong with you computer then, I went on another computer and checked it. There the writing was also basically the same size as the writing on this page.

Answer (score 1):

If $S'=0$ then your loglikelihood has 0 curvature .. i.e., your loglikehood is a line - hence it will either have a boundary MLE (if your parameter is bounded - e.g., $\sigma^2>0$) or the MLE will not exist. In either case, it is not guaranteed that your MLE will be normally distributed asymptotically.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I am not talking about it beeing zero everywhere, but it may happen at some pints. I mean $S'(\hat{\theta})$ must be zero for instance?

Comment: @user119615 The point in question is not just any point, but the true parameter value. In that case, if $S'(\theta)=0$ then the loglikelihood function is locally linear at the true value of the parameter and the standard error of the MLE will approach infinity as you collect more data...which is quite unexpected. This will not happen when your underlying model has a finite second moment, but can happen if you use a Cauchy or other distribution that lacks a second moment.